# S3 connection issue on pyspark 3.0.2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, airflow

I am trying to connect pyspark to s3 using the following code snippet. I am using pyspark 3.0.2.

How can I PySpark 3.0.2 be configured to connect to Amazon S3, and what are the key dependencies and configurations required for successful integration?

```
    self.spark = (SparkSession
                  .builder
                  .appName(self.get_spark_app_name())
                  .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
                  .config('spark.driver.memory', kwargs.pop("driver_memory"))
                  .config('spark.executor.memory', kwargs.pop("executor_memory"))
                  .getOrCreate())

    self.spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')
    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")
    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider")

    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.timeout", "10000")
    self.spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
    self.spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", True)
    self.spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.checkLatestSchemaOnRead", False)
    self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")
```

I am getting error like this

```
024-01-18 09:17:54,974 [reader] [reader] [DEBUG] :: Got request for reader of type: s3
Read s3 input data.
2024-01-18 09:17:55,293 [main] [<module>] [ERROR] :: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 79, in <module>
    res = job.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 106, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 132, in start
    raise e
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 129, in start
    self.execute(self.input_data, 1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/PosterRecommendation.py", line 448, in execute
    df = self.read_data()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/PosterRecommendation.py", line 440, in read_data
    df  = self.read(self.config.get('reader_config').get('mixpanel'))#.filter(F.col("date")>= filter_date).where(F.col('event').isin(rel_events))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 207, in read
    df = Read.reader(source, sc=self.spark, config=conf, topic_list_key=self.topic_list_key).input()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Poster Rec/Poster Rec/prism/src/shared/reader.py", line 410, in input
    self.final_df =  self.type.option("mergeSchema", "true").option('header', 'true').format(self.config['data_format']).load(self.config['src_addr'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/prism_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 178, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/home/ubuntu/prism_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/prism_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/prism_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    ... 25 more
```

I've tried using other spark boiler plate which uses

```
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.session.token", token)
```

Still it didn't work